# On a WordPress page template, what code can customize title and meta description?

Tags: php, wordpress

On custom-page-template.php, what code can customize the  section ( and <meta name=”description”) for all pages which are based on this template?
I tried using the following but they nothing on a page template. (They work on functions.php though).

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'custom_document_title_parts' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_add_meta_description');
```

Any idea, what code can customize  and  in a custom-page-template.php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in functions.php: (change page template's name in is_page_template)

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title_parts_array ) {
    if ( is_page_template('custom.php') ) {
        $title_parts_array['title'] = 'New title';
        echo '<script>document.querySelector(\'meta[name="description"]\').setAttribute("content", "New description");</script>';
    }
    return $title_parts_array;
} );
```

Or you can use this before get_header() in your custom page template

```
function new_page_title() {
    echo '<script>document.querySelector(\'meta[name="description"]\').setAttribute("content", "New description2");</script>';
    return 'New Title2';
}
add_action( 'pre_get_document_title', 'new_page_title' );
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, above code works in functions.php, but what I am after is how to use "wp_head" and "document_title_parts" in custom template code?